# What is a missing dna block error?

Tags: scripting, blend-files, file-format

I have recently run into some trouble with my project files. What happened is that the sd card I had them on got corrupt somehow (my computer did not crash and it stayed plugged into my desktop). When I found that the drive was corrupted, I bought a software program that can recover data from corrupted storage drives and was able to get the files "back". However, whenever I tried to open the file in blender (importing and appending included) I receive the following error: [image]

I did a little digging and found that it has something to do with the data structure of .blend files and I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to fix the issue? (Even if it takes some coding).

Thanks in advance for helping out the best you can!

Comment: It will depend on what part of the file is damaged. In a new file use `File->Append` and see if you can copy your object from the damaged file.

Comment: Wow, that's odd. I just had the same issue. Missing DNA Block Loading 'C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\Temp\myFile.blend' failed: Failed to read blend file 'C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\Temp\myFile.blend': Missing DNA block I'm not using an SD card but I expect that my file got corrupt as well. Last save .blend1 loads default cube
recover autosave option loads default cube the file is 28MB.

Comment: @sambler I tried that process based on a similar post I seen on this forum that detailed the same issue. When I append and go to the file it either opens up empty or I choose the object and it gives me the default cube.

Comment: If you can't see any objects to append then it's not likely that you will find a way to get anything out of the file.

Comment: AFAIK this can happen as the result of canceling render while synchronizing objects and then forcing Blender to quit.

Comment: If you have enabled the autosave File> Recover auto save.